# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 - Airbrake Ignore by IP Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, airbrake

I am using the Airbrake gem to report errors in my rails application.

Is it possible to not have reports sent if it has a certain IP address, I would like to ignore the following:

213.233.458.*

I have looked at the docs and noticed a method called ignore_by_filters but wondering how I would employ this to ignore by IP address.

Does the exception_data variable hold information on the requesting IP or any other way to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use:

```
Airbrake.notify e unless request.remote_ip == "ip"
```

request.remote_ip can be accessed in the controller, so you could just pass this to the model if needed.